# Cmake 3.10.2 not found in SDK, PATH or by cmake.dir prop

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake

Getting the following error when building my project in Android Studio:

```
[CXX1300] CMake '3.10.2' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.
```

My Gradle looks like the following:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-std=c++11"

    }
}

ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
}
}
```

I have installed CMake in the SDK manager.

I have tried to remove cppFlags and replace with version 3.10.2 and path to the Cmake file; this causes the gradle to not sync at all.

I've tried looking at other threads with a similar problem, but doesn't seem to be able to fix my own problem.

Currently running Android studio bumblebee.

Any tip or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 65):

While the latest version of cmake is 3.18.1, it looks like `Bumblebee` is still looking for ver 3.10.2 by some rules it defines, which ended up with a mismatched version error.

Makes sure Cmake 3.10.2 is checked and installed in SDK tools. By the way, check "Show Package Details" in [Android SDK] -> [SDK Tools] -> CMake, to list all available CMake versions.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: For me, it was looking for 3.18 v and I installed it.

Comment: I tried to follow what you did here as I need 3.19.6, however, the most recent versions I get whilst looking at Package Details are 3.18.1 and 3.22.1. Is there a way to add 3.19.6 if I have downloaded it directly from the CMake version archive?

Comment: @LukeBeveridge you can follow the official guide listed here https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#vanilla_cmake to customize a specific Cmake version.